# Using an exclusion wildcard in home .gitignore without affecting other repositories

Tags: git

I store my dotfiles in git using the techniques outlined here, https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/dotfiles In my home directory I have a `.gitignore` containing the line

```
# Exclude files/folders in same directory as the .gitignore file
/*
```

and to safelist my `.config` directory I have this line,

```
!.config/
```

I did this because I do not want to accidentally add stuff to my dotfiles-repository, and don't mind explicitly safelisting items as they need to be added to my config.

However, as a consequence, when I'm operating inside a Git-repository, files therein are ordinarily excluded essentially breaking `git status`. This is obviously happening because of this,

> Patterns read from a .gitignore file in the same directory as the path, or in any parent directory, with patterns in the higher level files (up to the toplevel of the work tree) being overridden by those in lower level files down to the directory containing the file. These patterns match relative to the location of the .gitignore file. A project normally includes such .gitignore files in its repository, containing patterns for files generated as part of the project build.

Intuitively, I would have solved this by moving my home-directory `.gitignore` elsewhere, and having a flag for my `dotfiles` alias specifying which `.gitignore`-file I want it to use but there is no such option.

Is there a way to solve this? Or am I flat out using git wrong at this point?

Comment: I don't understand why that `.gitignore` affects other repositories. Do you have something in `.gitconfig` making that file a global `.gitignore`?

Comment: You can use `.git/info/exclude` instead of `.gitignore`. Or use local config setting `core.excludesFile` to point to a different file.

Comment: It seems I had that gitignore file set as my global excludes file! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that my global gitignore file was pointing to the repository ignore-file, thus creating the cascading blocklisting behaviour described in the question.